# String substitution in unix (awk,sed.tr,cut...)

Tags: unix, sed

I've a huge sql_text string. I want substitute in the whole string/file the occurences of `:1`, `:2`, `:3` and so on with `:b1`, `:b2`, `:b3`, and so on. I've tried

```
sed -e "s/\(.\)\(.\)/\1b\2/"
```

but it doesn't work for the WHOLE string.

Comment: what's the characteristics of your `:b` stuff? does it occupy the whole line or what? have a try: `sed -n "s/:\([0-9]\+\)/:b\1/gp" your_file`

Comment: Reading [the `sed` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) should be a good start.

Comment: @ HuStmpHrrr . Tnx for your reply but It doesn' t work.I' ve multi occurences in multi strings file on AIX (not shure about gnu sed)

Comment: You have told sed to insert a `b` between the first two characters of the string.  If you want to match a `:`, you'll need a colon in the first grouping.  If you want to match more than once, you need to add a `g` flag after the final `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in Perl like so:

```
perl -pe's/:(\d+)/:b$1/g' foo.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'occurences of :1, :2, :3 and so on' | sed 's/:\([[:digit:]]\)/:b\1/g'     
occurences of :b1, :b2, :b3 and so on
```